# Why does pycharm uses lax security on macOS?

Tags: macos, injection

When looking at entitlements on pycharm CE for macOS, it shows many serious security exceptions. Here are its entitlements:

```
<dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
```

Why does pycharm uses such lax security? Is it necessary?

I tried to look into [pycharm's source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/python), and I saw this commit:

> Add macOS notarization script
>
> GitOrigin-RevId: e8779699a5c41df82848b335a3aed82b7550c7eb
>
> VladRassokhin authored and intellij-monorepo-bot committed on Jun 5,
>   2019 commit 631c91b

c1a579488452da099b957305502cda2f4

But I couldn't find a clear reason why pycharm would need these security gaps. Can anyone with knowledge of pycharm's code can shed light on this?